# C++ set with arbitrary comparator

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Pair {
  public:
    string lhs;
    string rhs;
    Pair();
    Pair( string l, string r ) {
      lhs=l;
      rhs=r;
    };
};

struct compare {
  bool operator()(const Pair& a, const Pair& b) const{
    if ( ( a.lhs == b.lhs && a.rhs == b.rhs ) || ( a.lhs == b.rhs && a.rhs == b.lhs ) ) {
      cout << "MATCH" << endl;
    }
    return ( a.lhs == b.lhs && a.rhs == b.rhs ) || ( a.lhs == b.rhs && a.rhs == b.lhs );
  }
};

int main () {
  set<Pair, compare > s;
  Pair p( string("Hello"), string("World") );
  s.insert(p);
  cout << s.size() << "\n";
  Pair q( string("World"), string("Hello") );
  s.insert(q);
  cout << s.size() << "\n";
  compare cmp;
  cout << cmp( p, q );

  return 0;
}
```

Invoking the compiled code gives:

```
1
MATCH
MATCH
2
MATCH
```

Somehow the set s ends up with **both** Pairs p, and q in spite of the fact that the comparator identifies them as identical.
Why?

Any help will be much appreciated!

***UPDATE:***

Many thanks for the great answers and your kind and professional help.
As you might have guessed already, I am quite a newby to C++.

Anyway, I was wondering, if Antoine's answer could be done with a lambda expression?

Something like:

```
std::set< …, [](){ my_comparator_code_here } > s;
```

????

Comment: my answer has a quick, simple and correct solution, just add a "!" :)

Comment: my answer was quick simple and incorrect - but i fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark B said `compare` represents an ordering and not an equality, by default it is `std::less`. In your case, you don't want the comparison to depend on the order in your pair, but at the same time, your operator< must be satisfy a number of [conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder).

All the answers here propose to change your specification and make the comparison order-dependant. But if you don't want that, here is the solution:

```
bool operator()(const Pair & a, const Pair & b) {
  const bool swapA = a.lhs < a.rhs;
  const std::string & al = swapA ? a.lhs : a.rhs;
  const std::string & ar = swapA ? a.rhs : a.lhs;
  const bool swapB = b.lhs < b.rhs;
  const std::string & bl = swapB ? b.lhs : b.rhs;
  const std::string & br = swapB ? b.rhs : b.lhs;
  return al < bl || (al == bl && ar < br);
}
```

At least, it works on your example, and the relation is reflexive and transitive.

Here is how it works: it is the lexicographic order for pairs: `al < bl || (al == bl && ar < br)`, applied to sorted pairs.

In fact your data structure is a (set of size N) of (set of size 2). Internally, `std::set` sorts its elements using your comparison operators. For your "set of size 2" `Pair` you also need to consider them as internally sorted.

If the comparison code looks too heavy, you could move the pair sorting into the `Pair` class, like implement two methods `min()` and `max()`. Also, you implement `operator<` and then don't need a `compare` class:

```
struct Pair {
  string lhs, rhs;
  Pair();
  Pair( string l, string r ) : lhs(l), rhs(r) {}
  const std::string & min() const { return lhs < rhs ? lhs : rhs; }
  const std::string & max() const { return lhs < rhs ? rhs : lhs; }
  bool operator<(const Pair& b) const {
    return min() < b.min() || (min() == b.min() && max() < b.max());
  }
};
```

Comment: This is identical to my answer, but four minutes later. I would hate to think that just because i pointed out someone else's error people overlook my answer because of an error it contained. - plus one for supporting OP's order-independence choice

Comment: @user3125280: Sorry, I really don't think our operator has the same semantics. I could be mistaken, but if it is identical, my presentation, code and explanation are different.

Comment: @Anoine yours code normalizes the order and does a lexicographically compare, mine does a lexicographical compare except for those that are the same backwards. Mine fail's transitivity but i'm not going to corect since it has been rejected by the community already

Comment: @user3125280: calm down, this is not a competition. I personally didn't vote your answer and the community can change opinions, provided we all stay civilized and rational and try to help each other.

Comment: @Antoine agreed - i upvoted your correct solution a long time

Comment: Great! Thanks to everyone for their productive and incredibly fast help. I am deeply impressed about the level of expertise that is available for free and with such a great enthusiasm. You guys are the best! (Josef Schmitz)

Answer (score 6):

The comparison operator for a `std::set` (which is an ordered container) needs to identify a strict weak ordering *not* any arbitrary test you wish. Normally a properly implemented `operator<` does the job.

If your comparison operator does not provide a strict weak ordered (as yours does not) the behavior will be undefined. There is no way to work around this requirement of the C++ standard.

Note that in certain cases where an equality comparison is needed it will have to use the `operator<` twice to make the comparison.

Also have you considered using `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` instead of rolling your own?

I've reread your question about five times now and I'm starting to wonder if what you want is a `set` of pairs where which string is in `first` and `second` doesn't matter as far as the comparison goes. In that case @Antoine has what appears to be the correct solution for you.

Comment: this isn't the full story though - the comparison does do equality as well, see my answer

Comment: this really doesn't answer the question - set only allows equality tests through comparison, having no equality parameter in its constructor, unlike other containers. So OP is doing equality *the correct way* operator< serves a different purpose

Comment: no it uses compare twice - OP can't and shouldn't overload operator< especially if he switches to std::pair since that would also be undefined

Comment: i will downvote if you don't correct the mistake i have pointed out, since you are giving incorrect information. sorry. OP can make whatever objects be equal that he likes. the quyestion has a solution, see my answer please

Comment: @juanchopanza it implies that it gives the whole picture - that means it is incorrect in my opinion. it contains facts, yet also say that op can't define his own strict order. what else are sets for? clearly op wants word order to be unimportant. why shouldn't that be the case. please read the docs on set before reconsidering

Comment: @juanchopanza have you even looked at my answer anyway?

Comment: @user3125280 I did, your answer is wrong. I think you need to read the `set` docs carefully. You have misunderstood something.

Comment: @user3125280: What the OP wants is invalid. `std::set` is a __sorted__ container and the compare function must provide an ordering.

Comment: @juanchopanza no i need to not do this at 2:41 in the morning - i corrected my answer, please read it and vote accordingly. this answer here still discourages the op from using the correct approach. i will reupvote once i see that fixed. sorry to offend poeple, i do have a pretty clear idea what i'm talking about

Comment: @Blastfurnace yes i agree with that part of Mark's answer I only disagree with the part that says these pairs shouldn't be equal

Comment: @Mark as I was saying from the start :)

Answer (score 3):

A comparator for a `set`, `map` or any algorithm such as `lower_bound` or `sort` which require an order need to implement a strict weak ordering (basically, behave like a `<`).

Such an ordering is required [to have 3 properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_order):

- irreflexive: `not (a < a)` is always true
- asymmetric: `a < b` implies `not (b < a)`
- transitive: `a < b` and `b < c` imply `a < c`

Which you will not `<` has.

Such an ordering defines **equivalence classes**, which are groups of elements that compare equal according to the ordering (that is `not (a < b) and not (b < a)` is verified). In a `set` or `map`, only a single element per equivalence class can be inserted whereas a `multiset` or `multimap` may hold multiple elements per equivalence class.

Now, if you look at your comparator, you will realize that you have implemented `==` which does **not** define any **order** at all. You need to implement something akin to `<` instead.

A simple, but extremely efficient trick, is to use *tuples* which have `<` (and `==` and any other comparison operator) already implemented in a *lexicographical* order. Thus, `std::tuple<std::string, std::string>` has exactly the order you which; and even better, `std::tuple<std::string const&, std::string const&>` also has it, and can be constructed very easily using `std::tie`.

Therefore, the implementation of a straightforward comparator is as simple as:

```
struct comparator {
    bool operator()(Pair const& left, Pair const& right) const {
        return std::tie( left.a,  left.b)
             < std::tie(right.a, right.b);
    }
};
```

*Note: although not discussed much, it is absolutely essential that the ordering of the comparator be **stable** across calls. As such, it should generally only depend on the values of the elements, and nothing external or runtime-related (such as their addresses in memory)*

---

**EDIT**: as noted, your comparator is slightly more complicated.

In your case, though, you also need to take into account that `a` and `b` have a symmetric role. In general, I would suggest uniquifying the representation in the constructor of the object; if not possible, you can uniquify first and compare second:

```
struct comparator {
    bool operator()(Pair const& left, Pair const& right) const {
        auto uleft = left.a < left.b ? std::tie(left.a, left.b)
                                     : std::tie(left.b, left.a);
        auto uright = right.a < right.b ? std::tie(right.a, right.b)
                                        : std::tie(right.b, right.a);

        assert(get<0>(uleft) <= get<1>(uleft) and "Incorrect uleft");
        assert(get<0>(uright) <= get<1>(uright) and "Incorrect uright");

        return uleft < uright;
    }
}; // struct comparator
```

Comment: < {"hello" "world"}, {"world" "hello"} should still be false, however

Comment: What if his `lhs` and `rhs` is not unique in its order (as seen by OPs original operator)? Would this suffice by any chance?--> `return (std::tie( left.a,  left.b) < std::tie(right.a, right.b)) || (std::tie( left.a,  right.b) < std::tie(right.a, left.b))`

Comment: @woosah that would make ("a", "b") < ("a", "b")

Comment: @woosah: you need to be a tad more clever and uniquify the representation prior to comparing the items, actually. This requires a bit more writing, but not that much.

Answer (score 1):

[from here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/)

> The set object uses this expression to determine both the order the elements follow in the container and whether two element keys are equivalent (by comparing them reflexively: they are equivalent if !comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)). No two elements in a set container can be equivalent.

Sorry all jumped the gun becuase I disliked another answer. I will exapand and correct momentarily. AS pointed out, an order needs to be implemented. typcially this would be a lexicographical order. Importantly however you still need to make sure that the case for which you consider two pairs to be equal returns false for both cases.

```
if (( a.lhs == b.lhs && a.rhs == b.rhs ) || ( a.lhs == b.rhs && a.rhs == b.lhs )) return false;
//ordinary lexicographical compare
if( a.lhs < b.lhs) return true;
else if( a.lhs == b.lhs && a.rhs < b.rhs) return true;
else return false;
```

Notic the "!", simple. Your code is saying pair one is less than pair two which is less than pair one. You want it to say that neither is less than the other.

DISCLAIMER STILL WRONG ON A TECHNICALITY, ANTOINE'S IS THE CORRECT ONE

Comment: This is, unfortunately, incorrect, because you do not implement an **order**, merely an equality test.

Comment: whoops - i just mean to return false in this particular case

Comment: @MatthieuM please see my correction, an undownvote if it satisfies :) thanks

Comment: @MatthieuM. oddly everyone jumped at the chance to correct me, but doesn't seem keen to reevaluate my corrected answer. Since the goal is to help OP this seems reasonable

Comment: @user3125280 relax a tad bit, you're replying all over the place. He'll probably come round to it

Comment: @woosah well it's got another error (transitivity) but there is a good answer so i dont really care now.

Comment: @woosah if i change it it becomes Antoine's answer so it's not necessary

Comment: @user3125280: thanks for the notification, unfortunately one is not notified automatically when a downvoted answer is corrected :/

Comment: @MatthieuM. it isn't correct, as you can probably see ("a", "c") < ("b", "b") < ("c", "a") but you can see what I meant, i only answered to draw attention to the order independence in OP's question which was overlooked originally

Comment: @user3125280: I know it is not correct (completely), but I do not downvote marginally incorrect answers, but generally answers that are either completely wrong or completely off-track :)